# Create a dynamic height width image component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, material-ui

I am trying to create a dynamic image component which will be using a material-ui `CardMedia` and will pass only height and width.

I have following code

```js
interface ImageDim extends StyledProps {
  width: number,
  height: number
}

const MediaImage = styled.img`
  width: ${props => props.width}px;
  height: ${props => props.height}px;
  object-fit: contain;
`;

export const BuyingImage  = () => {
  return (
    <CardMedia
      alt={'IMAGE'}
    />
  )
}
```

I am calling this from somewhere else like

```
<BuyingImage />
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, kindly checkout [Material-UI Card document](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/), since `CardMedia` is used inside a `Card`, and the prop for url is `image` not `alt`

As for dynamic height and width, simply pass the value as props seem to work good enough.

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  return <Image size={{ width: 400, height: 200 }} />;
}

const Image = props => {
  const width = props.size.width;
  const height = props.size.height;
  return (
    <Card
      style={{
        width: `${width}px`,
        height: `${height}px`
      }}
    >
      <CardMedia
        className="media"
        image={`https://via.placeholder.com/${width}x${height}`}
      />
    </Card>
  );
};
```

You can try it yourself here:

[image: Edit currying-lake-q6ipu]